# Pressure components, is it vector analysis?

Tags: vector-analysis, physics

I have a question about hydrostatics, but in my understanding of the issue, the problem lies in vector analysis. That's why I decided to ask it here.

According to the theory, hydrostatic pressure acts in the direction normal to the surface. Accordingly, for a profile of a wall in the shape of a quarter circle ([as shown in the attached diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOF0l.png)), the horizontal component at the deepest point is considered to be 0. However, I see calculations online suggesting that hydrostatic pressure can be analyzed horizontally as an increasing force from the water surface ([see the attached diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB4Qs.jpg)), implying that at the same point, the horizontal component has a maximum value. Therefore, these two interpretations seem contradictory to me. Can you explain why this works this way?

Comment: In one case the horizontal distance is $0$ while in the other it's non-zero. When there is no distance there is no pressure.

Comment: [Pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure) is the amount of force applied *perpendicular* to the surface of an object per unit area. In your first example, the normal to the wall at the deepest point points in the vertical direction; in the second, the normal to the wall at point B points in the horizontal direction.

Comment: The point of confusion really is mostly about the interpretation of hydrostatic pressure as a vector. It is very unclear how we are supposed to understand the second diagram. How is it interpreted so as to contradict the first diagram?